# cmd for loop escape ? in set?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, wildcard

Is there a way to escape the question mark in the for loop so that the following would work?

```
for %%a in (%*) do (
for %%b in (/? /h /help -h -help --help) do if %%a==%%b goto usage
)
```

It would be so much cleaner than separate if's. In a separate if clause %%a==/^? works but not here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to preserve wild-cards * ? in a FOR (no /F) command, the only way is via a FOR /F. Note that in this case the problem exist in *both* FOR's, so this solution doesn't work either:

```
for %%a in (%*) do (
   if %%a == /? goto usage
   if %%a == /h goto usage
   . . . .
)
```

... unless, of course, that /? parameter is not given.

Although it is possible to assemble a loop to iterate over several switches including /?, the resulting code is more complex than individual IF's. You may try this solution instead:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set params=%*
if "%params:/?=%" neq "%params%" goto usage
for %%b in (/h /help -h -help --help) do if "!params:%%b=!" neq "%params%" goto usage
```

Comment: That's a nice, working solution, except if the parameters are empty, the if gives "goto was unexpected at this time.", wonder why? Added `if [%1]==[] goto usage` first to check for no parameters and it's good to go.

Comment: Yes, but write that this way: `if "%1" == "" goto usage`. This is the standard way to do that...

Comment: Nice workaround! As for `if "%1" == ""`, it may not work well if `%1` is itself enclosed in double quotes. `if "%~1" == ""` may be better.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the "params" work-around failing when %* is empty: if you prefix %* with a space: `set params= %*`, it will not be empty in the `%params:/?=%"` and the comparison will not fail.